# Quitar relaciones en select LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Mi pregunta es la siquiente, al ejecutar esta sentencia en LINQ, me trae el usuario que requiero, pero tambien todas las relaciones de tablas donde haya sido referenciado por una foreign key en la BD, vale decir que si este usuario hizo 1000 ventas van a estar ligadas esas ventas al objeto usuario.ventas.

```
usuario = (from u in db.Usuario
    where u.UsuarioId == this.Id
    select u).FirstOrDefault();
```

Lo que preciso es quitar las relaciones que tenga la tabla usuario, o dicho de otra manera obtener solo los datos de la tabla usuario y no asi las otras tablas que tengan ligadas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una opción seria no crear las propiedades de navegación como virtual.
Esto usara el modo **Eager Loading**

Cuando quieras usar **Lazy Loading** entonces si usar virtual.

Ejemplo eager loading :

```
// Usuario
public class Usuario
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nombre { get; set; }
    public List<Factura> Facturas { get; set; }
}

// Factura
public class Factura
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public UsuarioId{ get; set; }
    public Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
}
```

Igual tendrias que usar **Include()** cuando quieras alguna propiedad de navegación.

```
db.Usuario.Include(f => f.Facturas).ToList();

// Tambien lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera
db.Usuarios.Include("Facturas").ToList();
```

Para acceder el Usuario a través de la factura sería de manera inversa :

```
db.Facturas.Include(u => u.Usuario);

// O de la siguiente manera
db.Facturas.Include("Usuario");
```

Para inhabilitar Lazy Loading de manera global

```
public class TuContext : DbContext
{
    public TuContext() : base("SQLConexion")
    {
        // inhabilita Lazy Loading de manera global
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; 
    }
}
```

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 2):

Esto ocurre porque tienes configurado `Lazy Loading` en entity framework, esto hace que se cargue las entidades relacionadas con tu objeto.
En el constructor de tu contexto puedes deshabiltarlo a través de la propiedad LazyLoadingEnabled en `Configuration`

```
Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

por ejemplo

```
public partial class TuContexto : DbContext
{
    public TuContexto() : base("cnn")
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Luego si en otra consulta quieres obtener las ventas u otra propiedad de navegación utilizas el método `Include()`

por ejemplo

```
db.Usuario.Include(p => p.ventas).ToList();
```

recuerda que `Include` es un método del DbSet

saludos

Answer (score 1):

Debes apagar el DeferredLoadingEnabled  que por default esta en on.

```
        //.....

        using(var db = new DBDataContext())
        {
            db.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;

            //TODO: query here.....
        }


        //.....
```